# Add a checkbox in Media Upload window

Tags: gallery

I'm developing a theme and want to put an internal gallery. Do not want to use all photos uploaded to the media library. I want to create a field (checkbox) so you must select which of these photos should be in the gallery.

I'm using `attachment_fields_to_edit` and `attachment_fields_to_save` to add the checkbox, but to mark each picture you must click on "Show" and select the checkbox.

Some time ago I saw a plugin that adds a checkbox next to the link "Show" to not having to open each one of the options and select the photos checkbox. I do not remember the name of the plugin, but it was what I wanted to do.

In other words, I add the checkbox next to the link "Show" for the user to click on this option and then click on "Save all changes".

Answer (score 2):

[Multiple Galleries](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multiple-galleries/) is the plugin that does what you are after.