# How to Add a Custom Colum on Thickbox Media Gallery Tab?

Tags: gallery, media-library

On searching for a solution, I found the following codes to add col on media page:

```
add_filter ( "manage_upload_columns",  'upload_columns' );
add_action ( "manage_media_custom_column", 'media_custom_columns' , 0, 2 );
```

The result is close to what I want, but I need to implement it on thickbox gallery tab-- I want to add an "Include" checkbox column for the media items.

How can I achieve this?

**[update]**
This checkbox would serve as the *include* part in the gallery shortcode `[gallery include="23,39,45"]`.

*But*, the shortcode is not written in the post content. The gallery is added for each post by a theme template.

**[update]**
To save the ids we get from brasofilo's scripts, I added name="include_ids" in the shortcode line and added this:

```
add_action( 'edit_attachment',  array ($this,'save_to_parent_meta' ));

function save_to_parent_meta(){
if ( isset($_POST['include_ids']) && !empty($_POST['include_ids']) ) {
check_admin_referer('media-form');
update_post_meta( $_REQUEST['post_id'],'include_ids',$_POST['include_ids']);
}
}
```

This will save the ids to parent post's meta if 'includes_ids' filed is not empty. Nearly perfect. But, when the tab is loaded, the include_ids field is empty, and all checkbox is unchecked. Users might think they need to check again even if they don't want to make change.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by "*include checkbox*". I suppose you want to add some functionality to it, no? I did some jQuery manipulation to add a virtual *image size* column in [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51165/12615). You may also take a look at the plugin [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields), as it does some heavy manipulation of the TB window.

Comment: @brasofilo , the solution you posted on image-size column is what I need. But, I also need this column to be checkbox instead of image-size. If a raw's checkbox is checked, that means the user like to include this item in this garlary. That's what I meant by "include" checkbox. How can I use your code to load a column of checkbox?

Comment: Jenny, I believe one has to completely rebuild the TB to achieve what you want... not an easy task, IMO...

Comment: I think I finally see what's your goal... Do you want this shortcode `[gallery include="23,39,45"]` built automatically based on the user selection through checkboxes? Codex reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode

Comment: @brasofilo , yes,that's the goal, but a bit different implementation-- When user post, they do not need to write done the shortcode. The gallery is added for each post by theme template. But they do need to go to Gallery Tab to make the selection.

Comment: What you describe is a very specific piece of software. But I liked the general idea and got [some help](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10907692/1287812) to cover the jQuery part and you can see in that question where I'm heading to. Will assemble an answer later on...

Comment: Doesn't work in WP 3.6 - try this new one instead: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/90114/enhance-media-manager-for-gallery/90504#90504

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While researching I found what [may be a duplicate](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/24879/12615), but I'm really not sure, as this one deals with sending the value somewhere else...

There, I learned that there's a plugin for what I was already coding (
[Multiple Galleries](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multiple-galleries/)) and it *injects* the `include` attribute when inserting the gallery.

Nonetheless, a worthy exercise and a joint venture with a [StackOverflow'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10907692/1287812)er.

---

#### Application

Appears in the Gallery and Library tabs.
The idea is to copy/paste the value of the selected images and use it manually.
Usage can be in a Custom Field, from where it is read in some template page.

---

#### Result of the Code

[image]

---

#### The Code

```
add_action( 'admin_head-media-upload-popup', 'wpse_53803_script_enqueuer' );

function wpse_53803_script_enqueuer() 
{
    if( $_GET['tab'] == 'gallery' || $_GET['tab'] == 'library' ) 
    {
        ?>
           <style>#media-upload th.order-head {width: 5%} #media-upload th.actions-head {width: 10%}</style>
           <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
            
             /*
              * Add Input Text Field
              */
             $('<span>Copy this to use in the Gallery shortcode as the "include=image-ids" (<a href="http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode" target="_blank">documentation</a>): </span><input type="text" id="shortcode" style="width:99%;clear:both" /><span></span><hr style="width:99%;opacity:.5" />').prependTo('p.ml-submit:first');

            /*
             * OnClick Populate/Depopulate Text Field
             */
            $(document).on('change','input[type="checkbox"][name^="gal-item"]',function(){
                var checkedIds = $('input[type="checkbox"][name^="gal-item"]:checked').map(function(){
                    return parseInt($(this).prop('name').replace(/gal-item-/,''));
                }).get();

                $('#shortcode').val(checkedIds.join(','));
            });

            /* 
             * Iterate through the Media Items and Add a CheckBox
             */
            $('.filename.new').each(function(i,e){
               var id = $(this).next('.slidetoggle')
                                .find('thead')
                                .attr('id')
                                .replace(/media-head-/, '');
               var filename = $('<label>Add to gal-list <input type="checkbox" name="gal-item-'+id+'" id="gal-item-'+id+'" value=""  /></label>')
                             .insertBefore($(this));
               filename.css('float','right').css('margin','12px 40px 0 0');
             });                 
          });
           </script>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: it works! Thanks for the solution and the time you spend on it! By the way, do I need to do anything to save the checkbox selection results?

Comment: @brasofilio , Now I understand-- need to copy the ids manually. How can I save it for later use automatically?

Comment: @Jenny : no automation here, you need to paste the value inside a Custom Field, so it is saved and can be used in your template...

Comment: I got an idea, I change "Copy this to.." as a hidden input field, then, hook it up with "Save all changes" to save the ids as post's meta. I will try to see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: If you are so kind, when you have the code, please add it to my answer :) Or, if they are major changes, post a new answer with your full working code!

Comment: I updated my question, added the ids to parent's meta. it might be better to add each checked box to attachment meta and have it loaded as checked. but that would require javascript and php exchange values. So, I added all ids to parent.