# Modify how gallery.js builds the shortcode [gallery ...] in tinyMCE?

Tags: plugin-development, gallery, media, media-library, media-modal

The post editor helpfully removes default arguments like `columns="3"` from the `[gallery]` shortcode. How do you tell it to remove a custom attribute that has a default value?

The answer at [Enhance Media Manager for Gallery](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/90114/enhance-media-manager-for-gallery/) shows how to add a custom attribute to the Wordpress 4.0 media manager. That code extends the backbone stuff in `wp-includes/js/media-views.js`. The shortcode is actually constructed in `wp-admin/js/gallery.js`, a tinyMCE plugin.

It's not purely an aesthetic goal to remove the default attribute. It would also help my plugin leave behind less cruft in the posts.

Comment: The file to construct the shortcode doesn't seem to be used anymore, I can't see it loaded. Were you able to do this?