# Extending Media Gallery - Retrieving values from short code

Tags: gallery, media-library

There are [some existing questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/90114/enhance-media-manager-for-gallery) that discuss how to add fields to the gallery dialog box and get those into the short code.

What I want to be able to do is facilitate *editing* an existing short code by pulling the current value from the short code and that value appear in the right field. My code so far is

```js
( function( $ ) {
    var media = wp.media;
    // Wrap the render() function to append controls
    media.view.Settings.Gallery = media.view.Settings.Gallery.extend({
        render: function() {
            media.view.Settings.prototype.render.apply( this, arguments );

            // Append the custom template
            this.$el.append( media.template( 'lf-advanced-gallery-setting' ) );
            media.gallery.defaults.cellPosition = 'left';

            this.update.apply( this, ['cellPosition'] );
            return this;
        }
    } );
} )( jQuery );
```

And the template is

```php
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-lf-advanced-gallery-setting">
    <h3>Advanced Gallery Settings</h3>
    <label class="setting">
            <span>Cell Position</span>
            <select class='cellPosition' data-setting='cellPosition' name='cellPosition'>debugger;
                <option value="center" <#if( 'center' == wp.media.galleryDefaults.cellPosition) {#>selected='selected'<#}#>>center</option>
                <option value="left" <# if( 'left' == wp.media.galleryDefaults.cellPosition) {#>selected='selected'<#}#>>left</option>
                <option value="right" <# if( 'right' == wp.media.galleryDefaults.cellPosition) {#>selected='selected'<#}#>>right</option>
            </select>
    </label>
</script>
<?php //Silence is golden
```

These two chunks are added in the appropriate hooks (because I get `[gallery cellPosition-'left'] for instance) but I'm not sure how to get the right values back on edit.

Thanks!